# Pagination. How to make moving between pages by clicking on numerals

Tags: vue.js, pagination

Tell me how to make it so that when you click on a button from a cycle with page numbers, this particular page opens. Switching along the arrows works for me, but I cannot understand how to switch between pages. I take data from Api. Total posts 98. It is possible to add your posts. On one page only 10 posts are shown.

My html:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="smallfon">
    <div class="blocktwitter"><img src="src/assets/twitter.png"  class="twitter"/></div>
    <div class="addTextPost">Add a post</div>
    <input type="text" v-model="createTitle" class="created"/>
    <input type="text" v-model="createBody" class="created"/>
    <div><button  @click="addPost()" class="addPost">AddPost</button></div>
  <div class="post1">
    <div class="yourPosts">Your Posts</div>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(post, index) of paginatedData" class="post">
        <p><span class="boldText">Title:</span> {{ post.title }}</p>
        <p><span class="boldText">Content:</span> {{ post.body }}</p>
        <button  @click="deleteData(index, post.id)" class="buttonDelete">Delete</button>
        <button @click="visiblePostID = post.id" class="buttonChange">Change</button>
        <div v-if="visiblePostID === post.id" class="modalWindow">
        <div><input  v-model="post.title" class="changePost"><input  v-model="post.body" class="changePost"></div>
        <button type="button" @click="changePost(post.id, post.title, post.body)" class="apply">To apply</button>
      </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" @click="page -=1" v-if="page > 0" class="prev"><<</button>
    <button class="item"
            v-for="n in evenPosts"
            :key="n.id"
            v-bind:class="{'selected': current === n.id}">{{ n }} </button>
    <button type="button" @click="page +=1" class="next" v-if="page < evenPosts-1">>></button>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My js:

```
export default {
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      current: null,
      page: 0,
      posts: [],
      createTitle: '',
      createBody: '',
      visiblePostID: '',
      }
    },
    watch: {
      counter: function(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.getData()
      }

    },
    created(){
      this.getData()
    },
    computed: {
      evenPosts: function(posts){
        return Math.ceil(this.posts.length/10);
      },
      paginatedData() {
        const start = this.page * 10;
        const end = start + 10;
        return this.posts.slice(start, end);
      }
    },
    methods: {
    setCurrent: function(id) {
      this.current = id;
    },
    getData() {
      axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`).then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
    },
    deleteData(index, id) {
      axios.delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
          .then(response => {
            console.log('delete')
              this.posts.splice(index, 1);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.log(error)
            })
          },
          addPost() {
            axios.post('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/', {
              title: this.createTitle,
              body: this.createBody
            }).then((response) => {
              this.posts.unshift(response.data)
            })
          },
          changePost(id, title, body) {
            axios.put('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id, {
              title: title,
              body: body
            })
          },
  }

  }
```

[Screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCeki.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add click event `@click="page=n"` in button

```
<button @click="page=n" class="item"
            v-for="n in evenPosts"
            :key="n.id"
            v-bind:class="{'selected': current === n.id}">{{ n }} </button>
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZOROO